# How to adjust the scale of map in Open Layers?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, openlayers, openlayers-3

I am having issue with OpenLayers scale, I want to be able to change the scale on the map
i.e: set the scale 10 meters / pixel

As you can see, the points should be a little bit up and the scale in meters and a lot lower than what is displayed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSoOe.png)

Comment: `map.getView().setResolution(10);`

Comment: @Mike this worked but still not what I want. My goal is to change the scale of the layers because the drawing is not as where it should be on the map.

Comment: What projections are you using for the map and scale line? If the map projection units are degree setting a resolution of 10 would mean 10 degrees per pixel.

Comment: I am using m so meters